# Traversing complex xml File in android

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

I have a xml file that is on this link

http://nchc.dl.sourceforge.net/project/trialxml/options.xml

I have downloaded and  parsed it successfully and also made a dynamic UI, but I have not used any of the predefined functions like `getFirstChild()`, `getNextSibling()` which makes my parser incompatible of parsing complex XML files having around 6-7 levels of menus.

Please help how to traverse a XML file,and dynamically create a UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `DOM parser`, to parse your xml document

**See this link for further details:**

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-xml/dom.html

Comment: oh got the problem, i was not checking node as an instance of Element.
\