# traversing DOM parsed XML

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Traversing complex xml File in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11932168/traversing-complex-xml-file-in-android)

In this i am parsing an xml file using DOM parser which is giving me dom1 as the parsed document.
the problem is that i want to create UI after this,and i am unable to the same as i can't find a logic to the same please help me with that.Also this is giving me wrong *getLength()*  values. What is wrong with it??

the xml is in this link:

http://nchc.dl.sourceforge.net/project/trialxml/options.xml

```
//this is function is called when i click my button
public void next123(View view){


    Element root=dom1.getDocumentElement();

    NodeList nodes=root.getChildNodes();
    create_Menu(nodes);

}

    public void create_Menu(NodeList nodes){


    for(int i=0;i<nodes.getLength();i++){
    Node node=nodes.item(i);


    if(node instanceof Element){

         Element child = (Element)node;
        String name=getTextValue(child,"Name");
        String typ=child.getAttribute("type");
        if(name!=null){
            z++;
            Log.i(TAG,"Names are:= " +name+ " ->  "+typ +"  ->  "+ z+ "  -> "+ i);  

             NodeList nod=child.getChildNodes();
            Log.i(TAG,"Length  : "+nod.getLength());


            create_Menu(nod);

            Log.i(TAG,"end");


        }
    }

 }
}
```

i have to create a UI after this, for that i am using ListView and an array of ArrayList to store my values. the problem is i have to assign a no. to every level,

for example if my array is test[], then

```
test[0]-> main, 

test[1]->1L1,1L2,1L3, 

test[2]->2L1, 

test[3]->2L2 

test[4]->3L1,3L2
```

please the xml for refrence.

Comment: yes , that is my question only. but at that time i didn't use it to make my UI, and then got stuck. so i thought of giving more details so that i may get specific help.

Answer (score 0):

I am just giving an example, try to do it this way....

```
DocumentBuilderFactory odbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
       DocumentBuilder odb =  odbf.newDocumentBuilder();
       InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
       Document odoc = odb.parse(is);
       odoc.getDocumentElement().normalize ();    // normalize text representation
       System.out.println ("Root element of the doc is " + odoc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
       NodeList LOP = odoc.getElementsByTagName("locations");
       int totalPersons =LOP.getLength();
       System.out.println("Total nos of locations:"+totalPersons);

       for(int s=0; s<LOP.getLength() ; s++)
       {
           Node FPN =LOP.item(s);
           if(FPN.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                {

           Element latlon = (Element)FPN;                                                                

               NodeList oNameList1 = latlon.getElementsByTagName("featured");                                       
               Element firstNameElement = (Element)oNameList1.item(0);
               NodeList textNList1 = firstNameElement.getChildNodes();
                featuredArr = changeToBoolean(((Node)textNList1.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());                                    // value taken
               System.out.println("#####The Parsed data#####");
               System.out.println("featured : " + ((Node)textNList1.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());            
               System.out.println("#####The Parsed data#####");

    }
}
```

Comment: see i have to create a UI after this, for that i am using ListView and an array of ArrayList<String> to store my values. the problem is i have to assign a no. to every level, and that is where i am stuck.the above thing that you have mentioned i have already tried.

Comment: for example if my array is test[], then test[0] should have main,
test[1]->1L1,1L2,1L3,     
test[2]->2L1,    
test[3]->2L2 and so on . please the xml for refrence